# Querying document property using struct as find parameter

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

## Problem description

I try to find documents stored in MongoDB using GO

## Current state

For testing purposes I created a small test program that inserts data into MongoDB and immediately tries to query:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type IndexedData struct {
    ID      bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    MyID    int           `json:"myid" bson:"myid"`
    Content string        `json:"content" bson:"content"`
}

func main() {
    // Create a client
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    collection := session.DB("test").C("demo")

    for index := 0; index < 10; index++ {
        data := IndexedData{ID: bson.NewObjectId(), MyID: index, Content: "Some string"}
        err = collection.Insert(data)
        if nil != err {
            panic(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Successfully inserted")
        }
    }

    for index := 9; index >= 0; index-- {
        qry := collection.Find(IndexedData{MyID: index})
        cnt, err := qry.Count()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v - %s", index, err.Error()))
        } else {
            if cnt == 1 {
                fmt.Println("Found")
            } else {
                if cnt > 1 {
                    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v - Multiple: %v", index, cnt))
                } else {
                    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v - Not found", index))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    qry := collection.Find(nil)
    cnt, err := qry.Count()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v items", cnt))

    err = collection.DropCollection()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

## Results

### Actual

`Successfully inserted
Successfully inserted
Successfully inserted
Successfully inserted
Successfully inserted
Successfully inserted
Successfully inserted
Successfully inserted
Successfully inserted
Successfully inserted
9 - Not found
8 - Not found
7 - Not found
6 - Not found
5 - Not found
4 - Not found
3 - Not found
2 - Not found
1 - Not found
0 - Not found
10 items`

### Expecting

I had expected to get 10 times `Found`

## Update 1

I changed

```
qry := collection.Find(IndexedData{MyID: index})
```

to

```
qry := collection.Find(bson.M{"myid": index})
```

and I got a working sample.

The documentation states:

`The document may be a map or a struct value capable of being marshalled with bson. The map may be a generic one using interface{} for its key and/or values, such as bson.M, or it may be a properly typed map.`

I interpreted a properly annotated struct will work.

## Question

How do I query for a document's property successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can open a issue.
I compared output of ***bson.Marshal*** for *bson.M* and your struct.

[image: output]

1 is ***fmt.Printf("%v\n", in)*** for your 36 row.

2 is ***fmt.Printf("%v\n", in)*** for [that row](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/bson/bson.go#L443)

3 is otput ***println(string(e.out))*** for [that row](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/bson/bson.go#L446)

Output for ***e.out*** is different for struct and map. I suspect it's a bug.
Also I noticed that there is not some test which test struct. All tests use *bson.M*.

Thanks for a brilliant format of question!

Comment: I asked on the mailing list where to open an issue ( with a link to this question )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about go but I would guess that you don't need the nil in the line `qry := collection.Find(nil)`

Comment: This is the last line. Anyway I do not want to filter in the client but limit to matching documents